# regex for access log in hive serde

Tags: regex, hive

I want to extract out (ip, requestUrl, timeStamp) from the access logs to load to hive database. One line from access log is as follows.

```
66.249.68.6 - - [14/Jan/2012:06:25:03 -0800] "GET /example.com HTTP/1.1" 200 708 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I tried with following and several variations of regex without any success. (The loaded table is with all NULL values indicating the regex doesn't match the input).

```
CREATE TABLE access_log (
  remote_ip STRING,
  request_date STRING,
  method STRING,
  request STRING,
  protocol STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "([^ ]) . . [([^]]+)] \"([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ \"])\" *",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I am not very experienced with regex. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test my regex.
You can also use this expression

```
([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:-|\[([^\]]*)\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*)
```

You get the following output

```
1.  66.249.68.6
2.  -
3.  -
4.  14/Jan/2012:06:25:03 -0800
5.  "GET /example.com HTTP/1.1"
6.  200
```

Answer (score 13):

Use double '\' and '.*' in the end (it's important!):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE access_log (
        `ip`                STRING,
        `time_local`        STRING,
        `method`            STRING,
        `uri`               STRING,
        `protocol`          STRING,
        `status`            STRING,
        `bytes_sent`        STRING,
        `referer`           STRING,
        `useragent`         STRING
        )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'input.regex'='^(\\S+) \\S+ \\S+ \\[([^\\[]+)\\] "(\\w+) (\\S+) (\\S+)" (\\d+) (\\d+) "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)".*'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/tmp/access_logs/';
```

P.S. Hive 0.7.1

Comment: Can you explain the reason for 'Use double '\' and '.*' in the end '

Comment: This is WAY more important than it got credit for.  The \\ is necessary because the regex is inside of a string that's part of a SQL query... so in order to get a \S, you need to type \\S so that you're getting an actual (i.e. escaped) backslash as part of the command.  \\S+ will match one or more non-whitespace chars.  \S* is just trying to match 0 or more uppercase S characters.

Comment: The .* at the end is just for cleanup, in case you missed anything with your matching groups.

Comment: The double \ saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wish the Hive, AWS Athena and other docs would include this example.

Answer (score 1):

Not fool-proof, but given that it is a log file in a known format then the following should work (untested in Hive, but works with `grep -E` and with http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html if you replace `[^[]` with `[^\[]` and `[^]]` with `[^\]]`). Assumes you only want the three values you specifically mentioned.

```
"input.regex" = "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[^[]+\[([^]]+)\][^/]+([^ ]+).+"
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s"
```