# Regex for pipe delimited data in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I need to construct a Hive SerDe RegEx for pipe delimited data.

Sample data:

> CEF:0|Microsoft|Microsoft
>   Windows||Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing:434|An account was logged
>   off.|Low| eventId=260 externalId=44 msg=Network: A user or computer
>   logged on to this computer from the network.
>   categorySignificance=/Informational categoryBehavior=/Access/Stop
>   categoryDeviceGroup=/Operating System catdt=Operating System
>   categoryOutcome=/Success categoryObject=/Host/Operating|Vista
>   ad.EventIndex=-972 ad.WindowsParserFamily=Windows 2008 R2|2008|7|Vista
>   ad.WindowsVersion=Windows Server

For this we need to separate out first seven columns by pipe and consider everything after that as a single column.

> *DDL: (CEF STRING, Vendor STRING, Product STRING, Version STRING, Signature STRING, Name STRING, Severity STRING, Extension STRING)*

So Sample data output should be mapped to columns as follows:
Col1: CEF:0
Col2: Microsoft
Col3: Microsoft Windows
Col4: 
Col5: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing:434
Col6: An account was logged off.
Col7: Low
Col8:  eventId=260 externalId=44 msg=Network: A user or computer logged on to this computer from the network. categorySignificance=/Informational categoryBehavior=/Access/Stop categoryDeviceGroup=/Operating System catdt=Operating System categoryOutcome=/Success categoryObject=/Host/Operating|Vista ad.EventIndex=-972 ad.WindowsParserFamily=Windows 2008 R2|2008|7|Vista ad.WindowsVersion=Windows Server

What should be the input.regex?

Also is it possible to have a Map data type for the columns in (key=value) format using this Regex?

Comment: sample output please sir !

Comment: Where is your code failing?

Comment: @aelor added the expected output for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I have no expirience with hive, but looking at some examples the following value for `input.regex` shoud work:

```
([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|(.*)
```

You might need to configure an `output.format.string`. Maybe the following links help:

- [regex for access log in hive serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102184/regex-for-access-log-in-hive-serde)
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201112.mbox/%3C6f4a3faf-9cdc-4c22-ba7e-5258ffc7fa76@sms-zimbra-message-store-03.sms.scalar.ca%3E

Comment: great answer but just as a note for those reading your answer: the OP doesn't mention but CEF allows for escaped pipes \| within the pipe delimited section of the header (how smart is that?) and your Regex doesn't seem to cater for that... e.g. Sep 19 08:26:10 host CEF:0|security|threatmanager|1.0|100|detected a \| in message|10|src=10.0.0.1 act=blocked a | dst=1.1.1.1

Comment: I also created a CEF parser in Java so that people can no longer suffer with parsing this format from hell. :-)

https://github.com/fluenda/ParCEFone