# create hive table from nested json data with flatten out fields

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I want to create the external hive table from nested json data but fields should be flatten out from nested json.

For Example:-

```
{

    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":{
        "nestedKey1":1,
        "nestedKey2":2
    }

}
```

Hive table should have format or fields flatten out like

> key1: String, key2.nestedKey1:Int,key2.nestedKey1:Int

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use **`JsonSerDe`** and create table with below syntax:

```
hive> create table sample(key1 string,key2 struct<nestedKey1:int,nestedKey2:int>) 
      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';

hive> select key1,key2.nestedkey1,key2.nestedkey2 from sample;
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+
|  key1   | nestedkey1  | nestedkey2  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+
| value1  | 1           | 2           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+

hive> select * from sample;
+--------------+----------------------------------+--+
| sample.key1  |           sample.key2            |
+--------------+----------------------------------+--+
| value1       | {"nestedkey1":1,"nestedkey2":2}  |
+--------------+----------------------------------+--+
```

**(or)**

If you want to create table with flatten out `json fields` then use **`RegexSerDe`** and matching regex to extract **nestedkey from the data**.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102184/regex-for-access-log-in-hive-serde) link for more details regards to regex serde.

---

***UPDATE:***

**Inputdata:**

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":{"nestedKey1":1,"nestedKey2":2}}
```

***HiveTable:***

```
hive> CREATE  TABLE dd (key1 string, nestedKey1 string, nestedKey2 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
('input.regex'=".*:\"(.*?)\",\"key2\":\\{\"nestedKey1\":(\\d),\"nestedKey2\":(\\d).*$");
```

***Select data from the table:***

```
hive>  select * from dd;
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+
|  key1   | nestedkey1  | nestedkey2  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+
| value1  | 1           | 2           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--+
```

Comment: JsonSerDe is something I can't use because fields have to be flattened. Can you specify the regex for the same?

Comment: @AkashSethi, please check my updated answer to create table using `regex ` serde.

Comment: this was just an example json and this regex is based on this.
anyway